# 'Unknown option' for my own package

Tags: errors, package-writing, package-options

I create a package: one common file that includes others. In common package file (`russian_post.sty`) I define options:

```
\DeclareOption{times}{\@seriffalse}
\DeclareOption{landscape}{\@lscapetrue}
\DeclareOption{portrait}{\@lscapefalse}
\DeclareOption{smalltab}{\PassOptionsToPackage{smalltab}{form_110}}
\DeclareOption{tinytab}{\PassOptionsToPackage{tinytab}{form_110}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{russian_post}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

after that I include packages, the interesting is

```
\RequirePackage{form_110}
```

In file `form_110.sty` I define them again:

```
\DeclareOption{smalltab}{\@smallt@btrue}
\DeclareOption{tinytab}{\@tinyt@btrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

And in my `file.tex` I try to use my package with this options:

```
\usepackage[times,tinytab]{russian_post}
```

This cause latex errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `times' for package `russian_post'.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `tinytab' for package `russian_post'.
```

in spite of that I've already defined default action for unknown options (just show warning).

The weird things come later: after ignoring these errors I get a right pdf-file.

If I move all `\RequirePackage` **before** options declaration block, latex works without errors but options don't pass to package. I know, that I can use global variables from `russian_post.sty` in other packages, but what if I would like to use that package alone?

How can this be so? And how can I omit such errors?

**UPD:***

Thanks to @Werner. I add minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{russian_post.sty}
\DeclareOption{smalltab}{\PassOptionsToPackage{smalltab}{form_110}}
\DeclareOption{tinytab}{\PassOptionsToPackage{tinytab}{form_110}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{russian_post}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{form_110}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{form_110.sty}
\newif\if@smallt@b\newif\if@tinyt@b
\@smallt@bfalse\@tinyt@bfalse
\DeclareOption{smalltab}{\@smallt@btrue}
\DeclareOption{tinytab}{\@tinyt@btrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{russian_post}

\def\testsmall{\if@smallt@b TRUE\else FALSE\fi}
\def\testtiny{\if@tinyt@b TRUE\else FALSE\fi}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[smalltab]{russian_post}

\begin{document}
small: \testsmall

tiny: \testtiny
\end{document}
```

It seems that the problem is in multiple inclusion of `russian_post.sty`. But latex should prevent such things when you're using `\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage`. I don't understand anything!!!

**UPD2:** it's more and more weird!

If I move this options to `\documentclass`, all works fine! What is it?

Comment: Do you load the package `form_110`? In the LaTeX companion book, page 880, there is a footnote saying "It is the responsibility of the package writer to actually load such packages. LaTEX does not check that packages receiving options via `\PassOptionsToPackage` are actually loaded later on."

Comment: @Guido, this package is loaded via `\RequirePackage` in `russian_post`.

Comment: [This minimal example](http://pastebin.com/BN5XcNhm) produces as output "test `opt` passed", as expected. It would be great if you could widdle down your current setup to something [minimal and self-contained](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that you can post here.

Comment: @Werner, thanks! I found it: that was because of `\RequirePackage{russian_post}` in `form_110.sty`. It is become now more weird: latex should omit such multiple inclusion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### General part

<sub>This [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175125/unknown-option-for-my-own-package#comment405242_175125) indicates, that a more general answer might be useful.</sub>

If LaTeX loads a package `foo`, then it defines macro `\ver@foo.sty` (containing version date and information). At the next loading request (`\RequirePackage{foo}`, `\usepackage{foo}`) it sees that `\ver@foo.sty` is defined and does *not* load the package again. That would be quite fatal, if the
package uses `\newcommand` (which a good package should do ...).

But it checks the options. LaTeX's understanding of an option is that an option adds/enables an additional feature. Therefore, if subsequent `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` calls of the same package do not contain new options, LaTeX is happy and continues. Otherwise, if LaTeX sees a new option, it cannot load the package again to enable the new option. And LaTeX complains. Example:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

LaTeX stops with an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.
```

Pressing `h` at the prompt reveals:

```
The package babel has already been loaded with options:
  [ngerman]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [english]
Adding the global options:
  ngerman,english
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

Or without global options:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
```

or if the first package loading is hidden in a class or package:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,english}{babel}
\documentclass{...}
```

Now, we reached `\PassOptionsToPackage`. It is useful *before* the package is loaded the first time, otherwise LaTeX options code does not see the subsequent option additions. And it should be noted:

- `\PassOptionsToPackage` does *not* check, if the package will be loaded at all.
- Also it does *not* check, whether the package is already loaded.
  (Perhaps a warning could be given in this case. A package could later
  check for new options, but `\@ifpackagewith` is limited to the preamble.)

### Specific problem

You have the following package loading order:

```
* \usepackage[smalltab]{russian_post}
  * \RequirePackage{form_110}
    * \RequirePackage{russian_post}
```

The problem is that `russian_post` is again requested for loading *before* the first loading is completed. The package file is not loaded, but LaTeX has still to deal with the options.

Workaround: Delay the loading of package `form_110` with `\AtEndOfPackage`, then
  the nested loading of `russain_post` is late enough to get LaTeX's option stuff of the first loading finished:

Package `russian_post` contains then:

```
\AtEndOfPackage{RequirePackage{form_110}}
```

The loading order/nesting of the test file is then:

```
* \usepackage[smalltab]{russian_post}
* \RequirePackage{form_110}
   * \usepackage{russian_post}
```

Thus the second `\usepackage{russian_post}` is not longer inside the scope of its first loading.

Comment: Thanks! `\AtEndOfPackage` fully solve my problem.